# elasticsearch multiple types and indexes in query

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a query like this, its in php, using the elastica library

```
$queryDefinition = [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [
                        'query_string' => [
                            'default_field' => '_all',
                            'query' => $term
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'must_not' => [],
                'should' => []
            ]
        ],
        //'from' => 0,
        //'size' => 50,
        'sort' => [],
        'facets' => [
            'types' => [
                    'terms' => ['field' => '_type']
                ]
            ]
    ];
```

i know you can run a query against multiple indices and types, using the REST api.

i would like to run the above query against variable count of types and indices. is it possible to do with the json query style?

if not how do i translate that query to REST style?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for curl - where sales is my index and order is my type (if you need mutiple type, use comma seperated values like ../sales/order,order1/_search ..), i used 3 field from my data i.e. id, name and status, and query string on name like 'shoh'

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/sales/order/_search?pretty=1' -d '
{
  "query":
  {
     "bool":
     {
       "must":[{"query_string":{"query":"shoh*"}}]
     }
 },
 "fields":["id","name"],
 "facets":{"Facet Result":{"terms":{"field":"status"}}}
}
'
```

Comment: yep, that's what i figured out in the end.